# SUM a list of values (contain sub query)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I currently have a bit of code that fetches the latest Exchange Rates and converts a list of values, as some of the values are in GBP already then I am using a CASE statement...

My question is how can I sum this query below:

```
DECLARE @cmd      NVARCHAR(250);
DECLARE @tOutput  TABLE(data NVARCHAR(50));
DECLARE @URL      NVARCHAR(100);

SET @URL= 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?f=l1&s=CADGBP=X'
SET @cmd = 'powershell "(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('''+@URL+''')"'

INSERT @tOutput EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @cmd

select 
SUM(
CASE 
    WHEN (PartsDatabase.ManufacturerID = 38) 
    THEN ((((PartsDatabase.ListPrice * (1 - PartsDatabase.Discount)) * PartsDatabase.ShippingAndTaxes) + (PartsDatabase.ListPrice * (1 - PartsDatabase.Discount))) * (SELECT * FROM @tOutput WHERE data IS NOT NULL)) * PartsDatabase.StockQuantity
    ELSE PartsDatabase.ListPrice * PartsDatabase.StockQuantity
 END 
 )
 ListPrice
FROM PartsDatabase
where PartsDatabase.StockQuantity >0
```

If I could put this query into a View then it would be simple, however im pretty sure I cannot have the key work DECLARE in a view but I may be wrong here

Thanks for any help :D

to add onto the answer below, I ran this code to retrieve the value in a Report:

```
DECLARE @value DECIMAL(10,3);
Exec TotalStockValue @ListPrice = @value  OUTPUT  

-- now the value is stored in @ListPrice variable do whatever you need to do with tit
SELECT @value AS [List Price]
```

Comment: You are correct. This can't be a view. A view is NOT a programming container, that is what procedures are for. Just put this in a procedure and it will work.

Comment: Not checked for a better solution, but using a Table Valued User Defined Function https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx may be an alternative to a View with less restrictions

Comment: if I was to put this in a procedure, How could I get the total value back? Im looking to grab this value to display on an SSRS Report, and I shall look in your link Matt Allwood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE My_Proc
   @URL       NVARCHAR(250) = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?f=l1&s=CADGBP=X'
  ,@ListPrice DECIMAL(10,3) OUTPUT 
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @cmd      NVARCHAR(250);
DECLARE @tOutput  TABLE(data NVARCHAR(50));
DECLARE @Data     DECIMAL(10,5);

SET @cmd = 'powershell "(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('''+@URL+''')"'

INSERT @tOutput EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @cmd

SELECT TOP 1 @Data = DATA FROM @tOutput WHERE data IS NOT NULL    

select @ListPrice = SUM(
                     CASE 
                        WHEN (PartsDatabase.ManufacturerID = 38) 
                        THEN ((((PartsDatabase.ListPrice * (1 - PartsDatabase.Discount)) 
                                  * PartsDatabase.ShippingAndTaxes) + (PartsDatabase.ListPrice * (1 - PartsDatabase.Discount))) 
                                     * (@Data)) * PartsDatabase.StockQuantity
                        ELSE PartsDatabase.ListPrice * PartsDatabase.StockQuantity
                     END 
                     )
FROM PartsDatabase
where PartsDatabase.StockQuantity >0

END
```

### Procedure call

You would call this procedure something like this....

```
DECLARE @listPrice DECIMAL(10,3);
Exec My_Proc @ListPrice = @listPrice  OUTPUT  


-- now the value is stored in @ListPrice variable do whatever you need to do with tit
SELECT @listPrice AS [List Price]
```

Comment: have look again I have updated the answer explain how to call this procedure and also the offending line of code.

Comment: Do you know how to call a Procedure in an SSRS Report?

Comment: @Crezzer7 In your dataset properties , for query type select stored procedure and make a call to this stored procedure from there.